# Quantile function error

Tags: r, quantile

I want to "truncate" values within a dataframe that are above or below a quantile.

Something like that, with "TRUNC" being a matrix:

```
for ( i in 1 : ncol (TRUNC) ) {
for ( j in 1 : nrow (TRUNC) ) {
if ( (TRUNC[i,j] > quantile(TRUNC,probs=0.995,na.rm=T) ) || (TRUNC[i,j] <
quantile(TRUNC,probs=0.005,na.rm=T) ) ) {
TRUNC[i,j] = NA } } }
```

But I get error messages like that all the time:

```
Fehler in if (na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)] else if (any(is.na(x)))
stop("missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE") : 
Argument kann nicht als logischer Wert interpretiert werden
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
In if (na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)] else if (any(is.na(x)))
stop("missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE") :
Bedingung hat Länge > 1 und nur das erste Element wird benutzt
```

So I tried a simple example:

```
A=matrix(seq(1,8),nrow=4)
A[2,2]=NA
quantile(A,probs=0.5)
```

which also gives me the same error.

Even if I try something like this:

```
B=as.vector(A)
quantile(B,na.rm=T)
```

it won't work!

I would be very thankful if somebody could explain a solution to me!

What is wrong with my code? Isn't na.rm=T supposed to solve the problem of NAs within a dataset?

Comment: I REALLY don't know why, but in this case, R won't recognize na.rm=T! I just found out that it works with na.rm=TRUE!!! Is there a difference between T and TRUE? I always used "T" until now.

Comment: Have you a variable `T` defined anywhere in your script above these steps? Can you try your setup with `na.rm=TRUE` instead of `na.rm=T`.

Comment: Try running `rm(T)` and do it again

Comment: it really only works with na.rm=TRUE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm... use `na.rm=TRUE` in your call to `quantile`. The problem probably is that you have a variable `T` defined as something else that is evaluating to `FALSE`. This works for me here:

```
A=matrix(seq(1,8),nrow=4)
A[2,2]=NA
quantile(A,probs=0.5, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, asb! 1 second ago, I found out by myself! (see comment above), but I really don't know why...

Comment: Not sure, why the downvote. If changing `na.rm=T` to `na.rm=TRUE` works, this is a valid answer.

Comment: ... you just edited your answer. Before it didn't address the actual issue.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, was that me?! I only tried to mark your answer as "accepted"!!!

Comment: @SeñorO: Yes, I did edit my answer because that is the right thing to do. Additionally, how are you sure that wasn't my original motivation behind recommending `TRUE` instead of `T`. I don't necessarily have to claim I know the problem when it can easily be verified. Never mind.

Comment: I checked whether T is a variable defined by me, but it is the one sample t-test...

Comment: You phrased your answer as though he hadn't included an `na.rm` argument at all.